# Hive query to select only records in certain percentile

Tags: hive

I have table with two columns - ID and total duration:

```
id  tot_dur
123 1
124 2
125 5
126 8
```

I want to have a Hive query that select only 75th percentile. It should be only the last record:

```
id  tot_dur
126 8
```

This is what I have, but its hard for me to understand the use of OVER() and PARTITIONED BY() functions, since from what I researched, this are the functions I should use. Before I get the `tot_dur` column I should `sum` and `group by` column `duration`. Not sure if `percentile` is the correct function, because I found use cases with `percentile_approx`.

```
select k1.id as id, percentile(cast(tot_dur as bigint),0.75) OVER () as tot_dur
from (
SELECT id, sum(duration) as tot_dur 
FROM data_source
GROUP BY id) k1
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got you right, this is what you want:

```
with data as (select stack(4,
123, 1,
124, 2,
125, 5,
126, 8) as (id,  tot_dur))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
select data.id, data.tot_dur 
from data 
join (select percentile(tot_dur, 0.75) as threshold from data) as t 
where data.tot_dur >= t.threshold;
```